# How to catch or redirect calls to TwiML app when not responding

Tags: twilio

I use an "TwiML App" which is an external service from a CRM tool and allows to make and recieve calls from within the browser. Everything is working, but how can I "catch" and redirect the call to another endpoint (a "real" phone), if **I've my browser not opened** OR the **browser phone is not picked up**?

Is this done with a regular TwiML Bin XML?
Do I need Functions?

Maybe someone can provide a snipped which I can modify.

Answer (score 0):

I presume that right now you have something that is responding with TwiML that directs the call to your [client](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/client), something like:

```xml
<Response>
  <Dial>
    <Client>yourclientid</Client>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

When the call fails or isn't answered, you can catch that and do something else with it. The best way to do this is provide the [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial) with a URL as the `action` attribute. When the call is either complete or fails for some reason, then Twilio will make a new request to the `action` URL. In that request you will get a parameter called [`DialCallStatus`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#dialcallstatus) which could be completed, answered, busy, no-answer, failed, or canceled. You need to build an application that can check the statuses and hang up the call if it was completed or `<Dial>` a new number if it was any of the fail states. You could use a Twilio Function for this and that would look like this:

```js
exports.handler = (context, event, callback) => {
  const status = event.DialCallStatus;
  const twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
  if (status === "completed") {
    twiml.hangup();
  } else {
    const dial = twiml.dial();
    dial.number(YOUR_PHONE_NUMBER);
  }

  return callback(null, twiml);
}
```

Once you've created this Twilio Function, take the URL and plug it in as the `action` attribute:

```xml
<Response>
  <Dial action="YOUR_FUNCTION_URL">
    <Client>yourclientid</Client>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

Alternatively, you might consider handling this with [Twilio Studio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio). Studio is a drag and drop builder for flows like this and allows you to do the same thing in a visual way.